# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "531772200000"

Tags: java, string-parsing

I need to convert the string `531772200000` to a Java `Date` object. The date is stored in a database.

When I am doing this, I am getting `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "531772200000"`.

My code:

```
String dateToBeConverted = String.valueOf(dbObject.get("customerDateOfBirth"));
String parseabledate = dateToBeConverted
    .replace("/Date(","")
    .replace(")/","")
    .replace("+0530", "");
dbObject.put("_id", String.valueOf(dbObject.get("userInfoId")));
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date;
date = formatter.parse(parseabledate);
```

Comment: When I'm doing what? What is this huge number supposed to represent?

Comment: Show us your code. How are you parsing the date, what is your expected result? Are you aware what the number means? Is it Unix time, but in milliseconds?

Comment: I don't see such a number associated with a epoch millisecond count nor a proper time format. Please tell us how this represent a date in the first place.

Comment: Is this unix time in microsecond or something else?

Comment: @Slanec here  is my code :

Comment: @Slanec 
String dateToBeConverted = String.valueOf(dbObject.get("customerDateOfBirth"));
  String parseabledate= dateToBeConverted.replace("/Date(","").replace(")/","").replace("+0530", "");
   dbObject.put("_id",String.valueOf(dbObject.get("userInfoId")));
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   Date date;
  
   date = formatter.parse(parseabledate);

Comment: I am fetching this string from a json object returned from a web service.
This is the DOB of a customer and i need to convert into java date and save it in to MongoDB.

Comment: @tobias_k actually , this is what i am looking for. How to make it parseable using formatter.Or is there any other way?

Comment: What exactly is the value of `dateToBeConverted`? From your code, it looks like you are trying to do some replacements but that the value that's actually stored in the DB is the epoch time (the big number). Is this correct? And is your ultimate goal to create a `Date` object from that, or to transform that date into a specific format, i.e. `dd-MMM-yyyy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a timestamp value, this will probably give you the date:

```
new Date(Long.parseLong("531772200000"));
```

which works out at Fri Nov 07 1986 18:30:00 GMT+0000

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that will provide the date correctly formatted.

```
String d = "531772200000";

SimpleDateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

try {
    Date date1 = new Date(Long.parseLong(d));
    System.out.println(newFormatter.format(date1)); //Will print out as 07-Nov-1986
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another solution is to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) with a solution below.

```
String d = "531772200000";
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(d));
DateTimeFormatter dd = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
DateTime date = dd.parseDateTime(newDate.toString());

System.out.println(date.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy")); //Prints out as 07-Nov-1986
```

Personally I prefer to use the second solution (Joda Time) as it is much nicer and easier.

Comment: Date1 was just parsing the Long value but I could have done it all in 1 line:
`java.util.Date date2 = formatter.parse(new Date(Long.parseLong(d)).toString());`

Comment: I meant that you can just do `newFormatter.format(date1)`. There's no need at all for `date2`. You are parsing the date, just to turn it back into the original date. Also, your output format should be `dd-MM-yyyy` (`mm` is minutes). Also, the parsing part does not work for me (might be locale-dependent, but I don't think so).

Comment: Good point, I've changed that now thanks. I realised I put the `mm` instead of `MM` but now I've changed to `MMM` as specified in the question. Which solution doesn't work? First or Second? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is epoh time format.

Somebody already answered about that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20732668/379779
and test your epoh time in this website http://www.epochconverter.com/